# error when launch the chaosblade-box in local

Tags: chaos

something wrong when run the chaosblade-box web project with the command:

`nohup java -Duser.timezone=Asia/Shanghai -jar chaosblade-box-web-0.3.2.jar --spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chaosblade --spring.datasource.username=chaosblade--spring.datasource.password=xxxx> chaosblade-box.log 2>&1 &`

note: mysql and the schema 'chaosblade' installed.

**errormsg:**

```
2021-04-15 20:59:29.358, [32mINFO [0;39m, [31m[main][0;39m [1;35mcom.alibaba.chaosblade.box.web.ChaosbladeBoxApplication[0;39m - Starting ChaosbladeBoxApplication v0.3.2 on CharliedeMacBook-Pro.local with PID 39353 (/Users/charlie/IdeaProjects/chaosblade-box/chaosblade-box-web/target/chaosblade-box-web-0.3.2.jar started by charlie in /Users/charlie/IdeaProjects/chaosblade-box/chaosblade-box-web/target)
2021-04-15 20:59:29.365, [32mINFO [0;39m, [31m[main][0;39m [1;35mcom.alibaba.chaosblade.box.web.ChaosbladeBoxApplication[0;39m - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-04-15 20:59:33.813, [32mWARN [0;39m, [31m[main][0;39m [1;35morg.mybatis.spring.mapper.ClassPathMapperScanner[0;39m - No MyBatis mapper was found in '[com.alibaba.chaosblade.box.web]' package. Please check your configuration.
2021-04-15 20:59:35.141, [32mINFO [0;39m, [31m[main][0;39m [1;35mo.s.c.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker[0;39m - Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c3ac505f] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-04-15 20:59:35.739, [32mINFO [0;39m, [31m[main][0;39m [1;35mo.s.c.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker[0;39m - Bean 'mybatis-plus-com.baomidou.mybatisplus.autoconfigure.MybatisPlusProperties' of type [com.baomidou.mybatisplus.autoconfigure.MybatisPlusProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-04-15 20:59:35.768, [32mINFO [0;39m, [31m[main][0;39m [1;35mo.s.c.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker[0;39m - Bean 'mybatisPlusConfig' of type [com.alibaba.chaosblade.box.web.config.MybatisPlusConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2d26293b] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
...

                       3.3.2 
2021-04-15 20:59:42.689, [32mINFO [0;39m, [31m[main][0;39m [1;35mo.s.c.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker[0;39m - Bean 'sqlSessionFactory' of type [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSessionFactory] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-04-15 20:59:42.736, [32mINFO [0;39m, [31m[main][0;39m [1;35mo.s.c.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker[0;39m - Bean 'sqlSessionTemplate' of type [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-04-15 20:59:43.214, [32mINFO [0;39m, [31m[main][0;39m [1;35mo.s.c.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker[0;39m - Bean 'deviceMapper' of type [org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-04-15 20:59:43.227, [32mINFO [0;39m, [31m[main][0;39m [1;35mo.s.c.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker[0;39m - Bean 'deviceMapper' of type [jdk.proxy2.$Proxy67] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-04-15 20:59:43.261, [32mINFO [0;39m, [31m[main][0;39m [1;35mo.s.c.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker[0;39m - Bean 'deviceRepository' of type [com.alibaba.chaosblade.box.dao.repository.DeviceRepository] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-04-15 20:59:43.487, [32mINFO [0;39m, [31m[main][0;39m [1;35mo.s.c.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker[0;39m - Bean 'deviceNodeMapper' of type [org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-04-15 20:59:43.492, [32mINFO [0;39m, [31m[main][0;39m [1;35mo.s.c.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker[0;39m - Bean 'deviceNodeMapper' of type [jdk.proxy2.$Proxy70] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-04-15 20:59:43.495, [32mINFO [0;39m, [31m[main][0;39m [1;35mo.s.c.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker[0;39m - Bean 'deviceNodeRepository' of type [com.alibaba.chaosblade.box.dao.repository.DeviceNodeRepository] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-04-15 20:59:43.663, [32mINFO [0;39m, [31m[main][0;39m [1;35mo.s.c.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker[0;39m - Bean 'devicePodMapper' of type [org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-04-15 20:59:43.667, [32mINFO [0;39m, [31m[main][0;39m [1;35mo.s.c.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker[0;39m - Bean 'devicePodMapper' of type [jdk.proxy2.$Proxy72] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-04-15 20:59:43.672, [32mINFO [0;39m, [31m[main][0;39m [1;35mo.s.c.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker[0;39m - Bean 'devicePodRepository' of type [com.alibaba.chaosblade.box.dao.repository.DevicePodRepository] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-04-15 20:59:44.665, [32mINFO [0;39m, [31m[main][0;39m [1;35morg.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer[0;39m - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-04-15 20:59:44.720, [32mINFO [0;39m, [31m[main][0;39m [1;35morg.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol[0;39m - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2021-04-15 20:59:44.750, [32mINFO [0;39m, [31m[main][0;39m [1;35morg.apache.catalina.core.StandardService[0;39m - Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-04-15 20:59:44.751, [32mINFO [0;39m, [31m[main][0;39m [1;35morg.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine[0;39m - Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.21]
2021-04-15 20:59:45.033, [32mINFO [0;39m, [31m[main][0;39m [1;35morg.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/][0;39m - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-04-15 20:59:45.033, [32mINFO [0;39m, [31m[main][0;39m [1;35morg.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader[0;39m - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 15465 ms
2021-04-15 20:59:48.592, [32mWARN [0;39m, [31m[main][0;39m [1;35mo.s.b.w.s.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'experimentController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'experimentService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'experimentServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sceneService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sceneCategoryLoader' defined in URL [jar:file:/Users/charlie/IdeaProjects/chaosblade-box/chaosblade-box-web/target/chaosblade-box-web-0.3.2.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/chaosblade-box-scenario-api-0.3.2.jar!/com/alibaba/chaosblade/box/scenario/api/init/SceneCategoryLoader.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error evaluating expression 'ew.sqlSegment != null and ew.sqlSegment != '' and ew.nonEmptyOfWhere'. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.ognl.OgnlException: sqlSegment [java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.hashCode()" because "key" is null]
2021-04-15 20:59:48.600, [32mINFO [0;39m, [31m[main][0;39m [1;35mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource[0;39m - DatebookHikariCP - Shutdown initiated...
2021-04-15 20:59:48.624, [32mINFO [0;39m, [31m[main][0;39m [1;35mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource[0;39m - DatebookHikariCP - Shutdown completed.
2021-04-15 20:59:48.642, [32mINFO [0;39m, [31m[main][0;39m [1;35morg.apache.catalina.core.StandardService[0;39m - Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-04-15 20:59:48.682, [32mINFO [0;39m, [31m[main][0;39m [1;35mo.s.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener[0;39m - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-04-15 20:59:48.694, [32mERROR[0;39m, [31m[main][0;39m [1;35morg.springframework.boot.SpringApplication[0;39m - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'experimentController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'experimentService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'experimentServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sceneService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sceneCategoryLoader' defined in URL [jar:file:/Users/charlie/IdeaProjects/chaosblade-box/chaosblade-box-web/target/chaosblade-box-web-0.3.2.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/chaosblade-box-scenario-api-0.3.2.jar!/com/alibaba/chaosblade/box/scenario/api/init/SceneCategoryLoader.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error evaluating expression 'ew.sqlSegment != null and ew.sqlSegment != '' and ew.nonEmptyOfWhere'. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.ognl.OgnlException: sqlSegment [java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.hashCode()" because "key" is null]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be caused by mybatis-plus, refer to this：
https://github.com/zhangdaiscott/jeecg-boot/issues/1886

Comment: it works after i upgrade the  mybatis-plus-boot-starter from 3.3.2 to 3.4.2